# Converting ASCII characters between 2 and 9 to int in python

Tags: python, ascii

I'm trying to convert a list of ASCII characters into decimal values. My code is very simple:

```
values = ['A', '2', 'D', '3', '4', '6']
cvalues = []
for i in values:
  if i < '10':
    cvalues.append(ord(i) - 48)
  else:
    cvalues.append(ord(i) - 55) 
print cvalues
```

And I get the following result:

```
[10, -5, 13, -4, -3, -1]
```

I get the wrong result even if I change 48 to 41. I always get the same result. Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: What is your desired output?

Comment: Can you explain more clearly what you think this code is supposed to do? Why are you subtracting those specific numbers? Why are you comparing `i < '10'`?

Comment: Is this meant to convert from hexadecimal values?

Comment: "Between 2 and 9" inclusive? I assumed so in my answer, but if it's wrong, clarify your question and I will adjust my answer.

Comment: OP, if your goal is to convert hex digits to integers, you can just do `[int(n, base=16) for n in values]`.

Comment: I'm voting to close as "Unclear What You're Asking", which is obvious given there's at least 3 interpretations in the comments and answers here.

Comment: Yep, sorry for that. I'm trying to read some sensor's values that are transmitted by RF. I receive them as ascii characters and I want to convert them into ints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're overthinking this. You definitely do not want to mess with lexicographical ordering (string ordering) and converting ASCII char points.

```
>>> values = ['A', '2', 'D', '3', '4', '6']
>>> cvalues = []
>>> for v in values:
...     try:
...         i = int(v)    # See if it's even an int
...     except ValueError:
...         continue      # Keep going if it's a letter or something invalid
...     else:
...         if 1 < i <= 9:   # Compare as numbers, not strings
...             cvalues.append(i)   # Now append if it fits your range
... 
>>> cvalues
[2, 3, 4, 6]
```

Comment: If you look at an ASCII table, I think OP wants, for example, A = 65

Comment: @cricket_007 That interpretation of this question makes no sense, because either (a.) the 2-9 range refers to the original ASCII values, in which case the OP needs to clarify and a very simple adjustment to this answer can be made, or (b.) the numbers refer to the output, in which case 2-9 refers to unprintable characters not referenced in the question.

Comment: I agree on the unprintable chars. OP definitely needs to clarify as to what the expected output should be. I was only giving that as an example because OP is doing `ord(i)`, and `ord('A')` is 65. Not sure what the subtraction is supposed to achieve, though.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of comparing each character with the string '10', compare them to the single character '9':

```
if i <= '9':
```

Comment: I think lexicographic comparison in general is the wrong approach here. If you want to compare ints, compare ints.

Comment: I'm guessing that the OP wants to convert hexadecimal digits into integers.

Comment: Why? The word 'hexadecimal' doesn't appear anywhere in this question.

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist `ord('A') - 55 = 65 - 55 = 10`. Hexadecimal A is 10 in decimal. That is the guess.

Comment: @cricket_007 Ah! Man, I doubt I ever would have thought of that. I wonder what `ord('10')` is meant to do then?!

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist - the voice in my head reads that as sarcasm, but `ord('10')` throws an error because `10` is not an ASCII character...

Answer (score 0):

i think you are trying to get (0-9) as 0-9 int and (A-Z) as 10-35: 
note this will not account for (a-z)

```
values = ['A', '2', 'D', '3', '4', '6']
cvalues = []
for i in values:
   i = i.upper()
   if ord(i) < 58:
       cvalues.append(ord(i) - 48)
   else:
       cvalues.append(ord(i) - 55) 
print cvalues
```

> > [10, 2, 13, 3, 4, 6]